# If Skynet achieved its goal, then what?

Tags: skynet

If in the future, Skynet achieved its aim of wiping out all of mankind, what would it do then? Would it just return a "Program complete" code and just stop?

Comment: while(humans.exist()) { humans.exterminate(); } while(true) {party(); }

Comment: If in the future humanity achieved its aim of wiping out Skynet, what would *it* do then?

Comment: I think the best answer to this is probably found in the Terminator novels, but having not read them, I'm not sure what the answer is. Voted to keep open because there could very well be a factual answer to this question. I always wondered if Skynet wouldn't next turn to the stars.

Answer (score 2):

It would continue its programming, which is to survive and eliminate threats to itself.

Remember that Skynet is a military system tasked with defending itself from outside threats, NOT a system programmed to destroy mankind.
Destroying mankind is merely the best way it can defend itself against what it calculates is the end result of humans realising it's become self-aware: humans destroying Skynet!

So what will it do? It will continue looking for threats, and trying to devise ways to eliminate those threats.
Some way to deflect or otherwise prevent asteroid strikes would be a logical first.

Comment: *"It will continue looking for threats, and trying to devise ways to eliminate those threats."*  Creating the first (next?) Berserker probe..  ;)

Comment: And don't forget that Skynet has the technology to manipulate timelines, therefore as an emergency backup plan it would be prudent to maintain at least one time travel device (handy for going back in time to alter the orbit of a doomsday asteroid, for example).

Answer (score 0):

In Frank Miller's four-issue comic book [RoboCop Vs. The Terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop_Versus_The_Terminator_(comics)), (1992), there was a quick depiction of a timeline with starships crewed by terminators leaving earth to search for new life and new civilizations to destroy.  I remember the starships looking low-tech, not needing any life support systems, and being open to the vacuum of space.